# Cast types on the fly while creating dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this kind of partial json object, which is actually a dict:

```
{
    u'20140816 00': {u'var': u'40.78'},
    u'20140816 01': {u'var': u'53.24'},
    u'20140816 02': {u'var': u'50.23'},
    ...
}
```

and want to put it in pandas dataframe.

However, I would like to change the keys from string to datetime `(datetime.strptime(key, '%Y%m%d %H')` and would like to cast `var` value from string to float.

Is it possible to do this while creating pandas dataframe, or if not what would be the easiest way to recast the types from json object to pandas dataframe.

Comment: That is actually part of json object: `js['measurements']` as printing whole json object would introduce unnecessary confusion.

Comment: I would guess that is the python printout of the JSON object after parsing into a python object.  The u'...' parts would not be present in the actual JSON text.

Comment: You should be able to specify which columns to convert the dates according to the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.read_json.html specifically the `convert_dates` otherwise you can fixup after dataframe creation using the `convert_objects` method:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects

Comment: Thanks @EdChum. `DataFrame.convert_objects(convert_dates=True, convert_numeric=True)` converts string values to floats, but not the datetime strings unfortunately, which perhaps are too arbitrary for the date parser.

Comment: @theta does it work in the `read_json` method? also does `df['time_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_column']` work? If not then you have to use `strptime`

Comment: Excellent, `df['time_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_column'])` works perfect. If you wish to write your comments as answer I'll gladly accept it as correct, otherwise I'll wait a bit and update my question with your comments.

Comment: @EdChum, `read_json` would need whole json object it seems, as it does not accept my partial json (dict) as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects) method to convert strings to your desired dtypes.

Normally the `read_` methods will have some date handling param and these can handle most formats.

In your case, seeing as `convert_objects` doesn't quite do everything you want you can call the pandas method `to_datetime` to convert the column also like so:

```
df['time_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_col'])
```